# Counting occurence with a condition using awk

Tags: regex, awk

Say for dataset

```
Jack apple
Jack pear
Annie apple
Olivia grapes
Olivia pear
Olivia apple
Jack pear
Jack apple
```

I need for each fruit how many times did a person buy it. For eg the final output should be

```
apple, Annie, 1
apple, Jack, 2
apple, Olivia, 1
grapes, Olivia, 1
pear, Jack, 2
pear, Olivia, 1
```

I don't know how many different types of fruit or how many persons. I am able to get the result for a specific fruit but need help to include all types of fruit

```
awk '{
all[$1]++
if ($2=="apple") appcount[$1]++} END {for (user in all) print user,  appcount[user]}
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using sort assisted awk

```
$ sort -k2 -k1,1 names | uniq -c | awk -v OFS=", " '{print $3,$2,$1}'
apple, Annie, 1
apple, Jack, 2
apple, Olivia, 1
grapes, Olivia, 1
pear, Jack, 2
pear, Olivia, 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -v OFS=', ' '{seen[$2 OFS $1]++} END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}' file
apple, Olivia, 1
grapes, Olivia, 1
pear, Olivia, 1
apple, Jack, 2
apple, Annie, 1
pear, Jack, 2
```

And to get **sorted results**:

```
awk -v OFS=', ' '{seen[$2 OFS $1]++} END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}' file |
> sort -t, -k1
apple, Annie, 1
apple, Jack, 2
apple, Olivia, 1
grapes, Olivia, 1
pear, Jack, 2
pear, Olivia, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An all-in-one `perl` alternate:

```
perl -lane '$h{$F[1],", ",$F[0]}++ }{ print join ", ", $_, $h{$_} for sort keys %h' file
apple, Annie, 1
apple, Jack, 2
apple, Olivia, 1
grapes, Olivia, 1
pear, Jack, 2
pear, Olivia, 1
```